# Scala : Create multiple sequence of case class with variables in it

Tags: scala, performance

I'm trying to generate dynamically a sequence of case class but I'm blocked at one point. I want to use variables in this function.

Here's an example of what I did (which is working as expected):

```
case class Example(first_name: String, last_name: String)

Object Example{
 def createRecords(number: Int) : Seq[Example]{
     Seq.fill(number)(Example("Bob", "Marley"))
}}
```

The thing I want to do now is to have the first_name and the last_name as variables in the generating process that would look like something like this :

```
Object Example{
 def createRecords(number: Int) : Seq[Example]{
     Seq.fill(number)(
        val first_name = generateRandomFirstName()
        val last_name = generateRandomLastName() 
        Example(first_name, last_name))
}}
```

Is there an easy way to be able to do that or I need to simply refactor my code and generate what I need with a standard loop ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is actually very close, you just need to replace `()` with `{}` to turn the argument into an expression:

```
Seq.fill(number){
  val first_name = generateRandomFirstName()
  val last_name = generateRandomLastName()

  Example(first_name, last_name)
}
```

You can also just call the functions in the constructor:

```
Seq.fill(number)(
  Example(generateRandomFirstName(), generateRandomLastName())
)
```

Note that `Seq` is a generic interface so you should probably use an explicit type such as `List` or `Vector` to make sure you are getting the type you want.

Comment: Thanks ! Actually my real code is more complicated than that and I needed to reuse the generated names for another field in the same class so the first solution is perfect !